# Problem with a potential leak

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

have a little problem with this code:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[button superview] superview];
 [button setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 VersionsPopover* content = [[[VersionsPopover alloc] initwithChapter:button.chapter]autorelease];
 UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
 aPopover.delegate = self;
 aPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(500,[self filesFromFolderWithChapter:button.chapter] *  60);
```

This

```
VersionsPopover* content = [[[VersionsPopover alloc] initwithChapter:button.chapter]autorelease];
```

is always getting me potential leaks.
With `autorelease` I get for `aPopover` "Object sent autorelease too many times".
When I use `[content release]` Xcode tells me that I don't own this object.
Without a release it says "potential leak".

Don't know what else I could try to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this.

```
VersionsPopover* content = [[[VersionsPopover alloc] initwithChapter:button.chapter] retain];
UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                 initWithContentViewController:content];
aPopover.delegate = self;
aPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(500,[self filesFromFolderWithChapter:button.chapter] *  60);
[content release];
```

Comment: Why sending a `retain` message at initialization ? The retain count should be 2... and `aPopover` should retain it too. I think without the `autorelease` message and a final `release` all should be ok.

Comment: Ya Vince, you are correct... But we don't know what happens in the code exactly. Since madmax mentioned that, `When I use [content release] Xcode tells me that I don't own this object`,  to take the ownership of the object, I suggested to retain that.

Comment: Ok, I use retain but now it says aPopover is a potential leak. ;-) Don't get it, because I release it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try initializing your `content` object without sending the final `autorelease` message.
Then do what you want with it, and finally send it a `release` message when you don't need it anymore.
There shouldn't be any leak at all.

Comment: How is it possible since you declare and initialize this object there in the code you show ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown should not leak or overrelease (apart from leaking `aPopover`, but I'm guessing you're handling that in code not shown here).

You could be overreleasing objects further down in the `VersionsPopover`'s `init...`, `viewWill...`, `viewDid...` methods.

Comment: How about the methods in `VersionsPopover`? Are you overreleasing anything there?

Comment: No I just release one instance variable and don't retain anything or so.